# AWS CLI create a folder and upload files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to create a folder in my AWS bucket and to upload all image files from a local storage. Unfortunately I have tried all possible commands given in the documentation such as the ones below, but none of them are working.

```
aws s3 cp C:\mydocs\images s3://bucket.pictures --recursive --include ".jpeg"
aws s3api put-object --bucket bucket.images --key mykey dir-images/
```

Also attaching a picture which ilustrates the 2 commands that I want to perform, but from the backend with the help of AWS CLI.[image]

Could you please help me write the correct command in AWS CLI?

Comment: Specify the target correctly e.g. `s3://bucket.pictures/dir-images/` and use `--include "*.jpeg"` (with asterisk). There's typically no need to attempt to create folders in S3.

Comment: Hi @jarmod this one gives me following error - `Unknown options: 
folder\myfolder,pictures, s3://bucket.pictures/dir-images2`

Comment: Well, the awscli support on Windows is odd. This seems to work: `aws s3 cp c:\mydocs\images\ s3://mybucket/images/ --recursive --exclude * --include *.jpeg`

Comment: Hey @jarmod, thank you this one worked. Could you make your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me on Windows and recursively copies all JPEG files:

```
aws s3 cp c:\mydocs\images\ s3://mybucket/images/ --recursive --exclude * --include *.jpeg
```

Note that you have to exclude all files and then include the files of interest (*.jpeg). If you don't use `--exclude *`, you'll get all files, regardless of extension.